# kentico IE 'Webpage has expired'

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, kentico

I have a Kentico C# site and I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.

I have a search form and its working properly, but when a user clicks on an search result item they are brought to a new page (suppose to happen) and then when they click on the back button in IE it brings me to a page saying 'Webpage has expired' but when the user clicks refresh on this expired page, the page with the search form and the search results come back.

My question is how do I get it so when the user clicks back it will bring them to the page with the search form and the search results and not the page that says 'Webpage has expired'?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589183.  It's a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value for the response in your CacheControl?  Have you tried using private, must-revalidate in the response?  Doing some research I also found the link below, which I think it may help you.

[forum 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1664698.aspx/1)

[forum 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1277815.aspx)

Additionally, one user reported that setting the cache the following way helps:

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);

    Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);

    Response.Cache.SetExpires((DateTime.Now).AddDays(1));

    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
```

We are monitoring our forums on devnet.kentico.com more often than stackoverflow ;)

Regards,
Boris Pocatko,
Kentico